# Suggestion of a library or a framework?

Tags: java, traffic-simulation

i am planning to do a vehicle traffic simulation as my under grad project. my plan is to simulate the movement of vehicles in a area. before starting any coding i would like to know of any java 2d libraries or frameworks (Eg:- game libraries) i can use, thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to ask here, http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check those links, see if they might help you:

[Java2d](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/index.jsp)

[JGame](http://www.13thmonkey.org/~boris/jgame/):

> JGame is an open source 2D game engine
>   that runs on any Java 1.2+ JRE
>   platform (with optional OpenGL
>   enhancements through JOGL), as well as
>   the mobile J2ME (CLDC1.1/MIDP2.0)
>   platform. It provides a very
>   high-level framework for developing
>   "classic" type arcade games. It is
>   based on sprites with automatic
>   animation and collision detection, a
>   tile-based background with easy
>   sprite-tile interaction facilities,
>   and high-level game state and game
>   sequence facilities. JGame games can
>   be run in a variety of ways without
>   requiring any changes in the code:
>   regular applications, webstart,
>   applets, or MIDlets. Graphics are
>   scaled automatically to fit any screen
>   size, from the smallest mobile device
>   to full-screen desktop PC. JGame uses
>   2D graphics acceleration where
>   available, but using OpenGL enables
>   better graphical quality.

[LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/)

> The Lightweight Java Game Library
>   (LWJGL) is a solution aimed directly
>   at professional and amateur Java
>   programmers alike to enable commercial
>   quality games to be written in Java.
>   LWJGL provides developers access to
>   high performance crossplatform
>   libraries such as OpenGL (Open
>   Graphics Library) and OpenAL (Open
>   Audio Library) allowing for state of
>   the art 3D games and 3D sound.
>   Additionally LWJGL provides access to
>   controllers such as Gamepads, Steering
>   wheel and Joysticks. All in a simple
>   and straight forward API.

[Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/static.php?page=about)

> Slick2D is a simple set of tools
>   wrapped around the LWJGL OpenGL
>   binding for Java. It's aims are as
>   follows:
>
> - Provide a simple 2D API
> - Make transition from Java2D to OpenGL easier
> - Enable distribution via WebStart without the complexity
> - Provide the tools required for most simple games out of the box
> - Extensible framework for flexibility
> - Mix and Match - you use what you want, nothing is enforced.
> - Help with rendering, sound, input, collision and anything else we can
>     think of.

And a list of game engines from Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines